# Problema con dropdown en barra de navegación

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, phpstorm

No funciona el `drop-down` en PHP Storm, utilicé `Bootstrap`

Estoy trabajando en el IDE PHP Storm, y con `Bootsrap` 4.3, sucede que coloqué un `dropdown` en la `navbar` con un menú para el inicio de sesión y el registro de cuentas; sin embargo al iniciar la página, el `dropdown` no funciona.

Ya coloqué los link y scripts de `Bootstrap`, pero sigue sin funcionar. Me gustaría que por favor me ayuden revisando mi código y me ayuden encontrando el problema por el cual no funciona el `dropdown`.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:active {
  background: white;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light text-esencia fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand pt-2 pb-2" href="/">
    <img src="{{asset('/img/Logo-Principal-2.png')}}" width="200" alt="Logo Esencia" title="Logo">
  </a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="/">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="/nosotros">Nosotros</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="/precios">Precios</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="/contacto">Contáctanos</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    **
    <!--AQUÍ COLOQUÉ EL DROPDOWN-->**

    <div class="nav-item dropdown form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <a class="nav-link text-light dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="dropdownNavBar" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2xl"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="/login">Ingresar</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="/registro">Regístrarme</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que debes especificar de manera correcta `data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"` para que uses `navarTogglerDemo03` como el **id** de el elemento en especifico, para que la barra se despliegue y muestre la información... He tomado tu código como referencia para un ejemplo y lo adapte un poco, espero te sirva.

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:active {
    background: white;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>dropdown example</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: white;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light text-esencia fixed-top">
        
  <div class="container-fluid" id ="navbarTogglerDemo03">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Precios</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contáctanos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```